# Getting mail-message contents in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

I am trying to get the contents (specifically the from field) of a mail message given a `BBBulletin`.

Code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/2gbej

Log: https://ghostbin.com/paste/aun4c

I can get the specific external id and the library id. Given the library id, I can get the `LibraryMessage` but I can't get anything useful out of it.

I can't use `MSNotificationObserver` as I have to use `BBBulletin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hook `MSNotificationObserver`'s `_didReceiveNotificationData` you should be able to get all the necessary information you need.

For a more in-depth example see [qrmail](https://github.com/twodayslate/qrmail/blob/master/Tweak.xm)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the header file from BBBulletin (https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/blob/master/BulletinBoard/BBBulletin.h)

At around line 111 you find the properties you are seemingly looking for.

```
....
@property(readonly, nonatomic) int primaryAttachmentType;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *section;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *message;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
...
```

Comment: This doesn't have all the information required to reply to an email. Mainly the 'from' field.